# Creating a loop itinerary

Tags: algorithm, direction

I am trying to find a way to create a loop itinerary. For example, I know my starting position, and I want to walk some distance and come back to my starting point.

It's quite easy to find itinerary from point A => B, but I want to force an itinerary from A => A. Of course, one parameter would be the distance I want to walk.

I am looking for an algorithm, but open for any tools implementing it.

An easy solution is to pick a random point (R) near the starting point, and then calculate itinerary from A => R and then R => A. But itinerary created this way results most of the time in exactly the invert path, so it's not really a loop.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: There are an infinite number of potential paths for any distance greater than zero, so your problem, as stated, has no solution.

Comment: If you just want a tool to do this, I use https://routeshuffle.com/ to help me find running loops

Comment: Vince, my problem has infinite solution, not none. Tanks alphabeta

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a closed loop Travelling Salesman Problem algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Also the Hamiltonian Path Problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: Do you mean that i should have random points and then link them? I though about the salesman problem, but it means that you already knows your different points. Here i want to generate a random itinerary from my starting point.

Comment: Yer ok, so have a look at how they generate the route and then essentially you just need to randomize some of the inputs. Because you will be randomizing a route, you may need a bounds/max distance constant - some kind of geographic constant otherwise your route could be infinite.